# How to define a template to re-use a SVG graphic button in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

For a dashboard html page, I need a lot of round buttons with a "-" or "+" sign.

This is how the buttons look:

[image: buttons]

The code below works fine in Chromium.

Repeating the complete design for each button makes the code hard to read.

For each button, only the **id** and the text **+/-** change.

Is there a way to define this as a **button template** and **resuse** the button?

```html
<div class="item2" style="padding: 0px">
                <svg id="minus1" height="60" width="60">
                    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="28" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white"/>
                    <text x="15" y="48" fill="black" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 50px;text-align: center;user-select: none">-</text>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="item2" style="padding: 0px">
                <svg id="plus1" height="60" width="60">
                    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="28" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white"/>
                    <text x="15" y="48" fill="black" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 50px;text-align: center;user-select: none">+</text>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="item1"></div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: wrap the content of the svg element in a group `<g>` with an id and reuse the group with a `<use>` element in other svg element

Answer (score 1):

### What you can do

Reference the svgs content by an `id` with `xlink:href` from a `<use>` tag.

### How to do it

1. Group the content of each `<svg>` into a single tag (if not already), so you can reference it later by adding an `id` to it.
2. Wrap the grouped contents which share the same `viewBox` (boundings, in your case, all of them), into a single `<defs>` tag, a tag made to store content to be used later.
3. Put the `<defs>` into a `<svg>` holding that `viewBox` information.
4. Put the final `<svg>` in your `<body>` (usually at the top).

### E.g.

Example with some modifications:

```css
text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.svg-container {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  user-select: none;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 60 60" style="display: none">
    <defs>
      <g id="minus">
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="28" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white"/>
        <text x="21" y="44" fill="black">-</text>
      </g>
      <g id="plus">
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="28" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="white"/>
        <text x="15" y="48" fill="black">+</text>
      </g>
    </defs>
  </svg>

  <!-- somewhere in your code -->
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href="#minus" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg>
      <use xlink:href="#plus" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```